# Ivona воспроизвести набранный текст

Tags: linux, ubuntu

как воспроизвести звуковой поток через  аудиоплеер(IvonaspeechCloud)

Comment: Эм.. в заголовке и в теме вопроса по-моему разные задачи. А теги вообще не понятно при чём. Тебе надо из текстового файла в убунте получить звуковой файл через api `ivona`? Или у тебя уже есть этот звуковой файл полученный через api и тебе его надо воспроизвести?